# Underdetermined Linear System

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, systems-of-equations

What I want to show:
A homogeneous system of linear equations, with fewer equations(m) than unknowns(n), has a non-trivial solution.

Lemma Used:
Suppose you have a system of linear equations with n unknowns. Write the as $Ax=b$. Let $E$ be the systems reduced echelon matrix. If $E$ has k non-zero rows then then system will have $n-k>0$ free variables.

How do I prove this lemma (without using rank?)

Proof of what I want to show:
So, if I have a system of equations $Ax=\textbf{0}$ with fewer equations then unknowns then I can reduce A to its unique Hermite matrix, $E$. (Hermite is its reduced echelon matrix). Further suppose $E$ is non-zero then Either it has a zero row or not. If it has a zero row then since the number of rows are less than the number of columns, we will have a solution  with $n-k>0$ free variables, in which k is the number of non-zero rows (as $k\leq m<n$). If it does not have a zero row, then we will have $n-m>0$ solutions.

Is this proof correct? (Do not use rank, please)

Comment: Doesn’t your argument essentially use matrix rank, anyway, just avoiding the term per se?

Comment: A system of homogeneous linear equations over a field of characteristic 0 has either no solutions or an infinite number of them. Your last sentence claims that it might have some other, finite number of solutions. At any rate, why does that case need to be examined separately? It’s also covered by the lemma.